# BeautifulSoup: Find all the content in <p> tag between two <h2> tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a webpage to parse, the source is as follows:

```
<div class=WordSection1>

<p class=MsoTitle><a name="_nvfbzzqeywr7"></a><span lang=EN>Geometry</span></p>
<h2><a name="_99n9742wmg4y"></a><span lang=EN>Algebraic Geometry </span></h2>

<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=EN>It is a type of geometry which deals with
zeros of multivariate polynomial. It consists of linear and polynomial
algebraic equations used to solve the sets of zeros. The uses of this type <span
class=GramE>consists</span> of Cryptography, String theory, etc.</span></p>

<h2><a name="_64xtqrllvykm"></a><span lang=EN>Discrete Geometry</span></h2>

<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=EN>It is a type of Geometry, mainly concerned
with the relative position of simple geometric objects, such as points, lines,
Triangles, Circles, etc.</span></p>

<h2><a name="_mdul98ybu9wv"></a><span lang=EN>Differential Geometry</span></h2>

<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=EN>It uses techniques of algebra and calculus for
problem solving. The different problem involves general relativity in physics <span
class=SpellE><span class=GramE>etc</span></span><span class=GramE>,.</span></span></p>

</div>
```

I want to parse data inside in form of list and the corresponding  tag in another list so that I can map it later in form of python dictionary.I even have to ignore other  tags like h1 and h3.

Expected Results:

```py
headers = ['Algebraic Geometry','Discrete Geometry','Differential Geometry']
content = ['It is a type of geometry which deals with
zeros of multivariate polynomial. It consists of linear and polynomial
algebraic equations used to solve the sets of zeros. The uses of this type consists of Cryptography, String theory, etc.','It is a type of Geometry, mainly concerned
with the relative position of simple geometric objects, such as points, lines,
Triangles, Circles, etc.','It uses techniques of algebra and calculus for
problem solving. The different problem involves general relativity in physics etc,.']
```

I am able to get all headers.But for getting

tags inside headers, I am unable to get the results. Here's what I have tried:

```py
content = []

# find the node with id of "WordSection1"
mark = soup.find_all(class_="WordSection1")
print(mark)

# walk through the siblings of the parent (H2) node 
# until we reach the next H2 node
for elt in mark.parent.nextSiblingGenerator():
    if elt.name == "h2":
        break
    if hasattr(elt, "text"):
        content.append(elt.text)
```

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution. If we just follow your example code, FireM's answer is right. You should post your entire HTML structure.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = 'your html'
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
h2s = doc.selects('div.WordSection1>h2')
ps = h2s.next.text
h2s = h2s.text
print (h2s)
print (ps)
```

Result:

```
['Algebraic Geometry', 'Discrete Geometry', 'Differential Geometry']
['It is a type of geometry which deals with zeros of multivariate polynomial. It consists of linear and polynomial algebraic equations used to solve the sets of zeros. The uses of this type consists of Cryptography, String theory, etc.', 'It is a type of Geometry, mainly concerned with the relative position of simple geometric objects, such as points, lines, Triangles, Circles, etc.', 'It uses techniques of algebra and calculus for problem solving. The different problem involves general relativity in physics etc,.']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need

````
# read html code snippet
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# find the node with id of "WordSection1"
mark = soup.find(class_="WordSection1")

# initialize container objects
headers = []
content = []

# get all h2 and p(with class MsoNormal) tags
find_headers = mark.find_all_next('h2')
find_content = mark.find_all_next('p', {'class': 'MsoNormal'})

# get text of tags
for head, cont in zip(find_headers, find_content):
   headers.append(head.text)
   content.append(cont.text)

# output lists
print(f"Headers = {headers} '\n\nContent = {content}")```
````

Comment: It is working but failing for the case where <h1> tag which is before <h2> tag. For that, it takes the content of <p> which is inside <h1>.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to express this in [Web Scraping Language](https://github.com/whatsdis/web-scraping-language) using Xpath

```
GOTO targeturl.com
EXTRACT {'header': '//h2/preceding-sibling::p[@class="MsoNormal"]', 
         'desc': '//p[@class="MsoNormal"]/following-sibling::h2'}
```

This should yield an array of headers and descriptions. However, because neither two fields are contained within a parent, if one of the entries is missing a description, you will not get a one to one match.